# Wine and Counter Strike Global Offensive no steam

Tags: wine

Does anyone could play CS:GO no steam with wine in Ubuntu 14.04? I want to test it first before buy. I have tried but i fail, steam client needed error. I know CS:GO steam works with wine, but does cs:go no steam work with wine?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it works, but sometimes with some problems.

See [CS:GO in Wine, fullscreen freezes when Alt-Tabing and overlaps everything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523033/csgo-in-wine-fullscreen-freezes-when-alt-tabing-and-overlaps-everything), including [dobey](https://askubuntu.com/users/50737/dobey)'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523033/csgo-in-wine-fullscreen-freezes-when-alt-tabing-and-overlaps-everything#comment711860_523033):

> It's an issue with wine. Change the game settings to not be full screen and it will be fine.

Basically, you may have to run it in windowed mode.

Also see [the Wine AppDB page for CS:GO](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13949), and particularly [**this page**](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26545) (as that's close to the version of the game you're likely attempting to run):

> What works
>
> - The game
>
> What does not
>
> - Steam overlay
> - Lighting, objects shine through walls with multicore rendering enabled (default setting)

That page also mentions: "The Steam overlay MUST be disabled or the game will either not recognise any keyboard input or crash on pressing a key."

Comment: The first link you gave is dead. Please update it.